# Подскажите правильное написание условия PHP

Tags: php

Какое условие здесь используется? Или цикл?. (Сейчас есть подобное в ВК):

1. Например если $mesasge = "гол" то должно сработать условие какое-то (неважно какое, припустим пусть просто вернет true)
2. НО также условие должно возвращать true если слово "гол" написано как "гоооол".

Накидайте примеров реализации подобного. Лично мне непонятен только 2 пункт.

Comment: Регулярные выражения есть для этого

Comment: А если `if ($str == 'gol' || $str == 'gooool') return true;`? Не вариант в таком виде?

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
$pattern = "/^г[о]{1,}л$/";
$flag = preg_match($pattern, "гол");
echo $flag; //true
$flag = preg_match($pattern, "гоооол");
echo $flag; //true
$flag = preg_match($pattern, "строка");
echo $flag; //false
```

Comment: Нет необходимости писать символьный класс `[...]` ради символьного класса. А вместо уточняющих квантификаторов `{1,}` было бы удобнее использовать метасимвол `+`: `'~\bго+л\b~iu'`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения в комбинации с пользовательской функцией, возвращающей булево значение:

```
$str = 'Гоооол!';
var_dump( goal($str) ); // boolean true

function goal($s) {
    return (bool) preg_match('~\bго+л\b~iu', $s);
}
```